# Issue with data attributes not storing values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remember and modify values based on radio selections. If radio1 is selected, it should read value1 and value 2's values and save them as the data attribute "previous-value", and then set those values to either 0 or 1. If radio2 is selected, then value1 should be set to 0, and value2 should be set to the previous-value. However that is not happening, the previous-value data doesnt seem to be setting. I don't have any console errors. I'm wondering if setting the values and changing the values with the same action is causing an issue.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
var $value1 = $('#value1');
var $value2 = $('#value2');

if($(this).attr('id') == 'radio1') { 
  $value1.data('previousvalue', $value1.val());
  $value1.val('1');

  $value2.data('previousvalue', $value2.val());
  $value2.val('0');


} else if($(this).attr('id') == 'radio2') {      
  $value1.val('0');
  $value2.val($value2.data('previousvalue'));
}
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nz62pgwq/  Your script appears to do what you have written it to do.

Comment: You may find [attr. vs prop.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) interesting. setting $.data(), is setting the dom property, and not the attribute value. You can check the latest value of the elements $.data(), it will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

First you do a `queryselectorAll` so as to get all inputs type radio. It return a *nodelist*. After we do a loop of it with "*for*" and in that *loop* we do a condition "if" so as to verify if the `radioButtons[i]` is cheeked. And if its the case it show a message showing the `selectedOne`.

Try this code:

```
let radioButtons=document.querySelectorAll(input[type="radio"]); 
for(let i=0,c=radioButtons.length;i<c;i++){
    if(radioButtons[i].checked){
        alert("am the selectedOne "+radioButtons [i]);
      }
 }
```

Comment: You should try to explain your answer and not just "code drop"  --  If your answer does, in fact, solve the OP's issue .. Explain how, and why.

Comment: Ok first you do a queryselectorAll so as to get all inputs type radio. It return a nodelist. After we do a loop of it with "for" and in that loop we do a condition "if" so as to verify if the radioButtons[i] is cheeked. And if its the case it show a message showing the selectedOne